# Meteor, near-simultaneous user actions (chat messages)

Tags: meteor

I observed an issue on
http://instachat.meteor.com/room/General . (The question might be InstaChat-specifific or Meteor-specific.)

In one browser I typed "uno", in the other "dos", then I hit enter in each of the two browsers (in very quick succession). One of the two messages got lost.

Tried it again:

Wrote each message, entered in Firefox and then immediately entered in Safari - both messages got lost (gone from the message field and not displayed in the chat history).

Is this an issue that Meteor has? Or just InstaChat?

Tobi

Comment: I doubt that this is a Meteor-specific bug. Can you post the source or a gist? Hard to tell just from the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is gone, might have been reolved by the Meteor guys.